# Как заархивировать все папки в текущем каталоге, кажую в отдельный архив

Tags: linux, tar

Например имеем в текущем каталоге папки `001,002,003`.

На выходе надо иметь три архива `001.tar.gz, 002.tar.gz, 003.tar.gz`

Comment: `$ for d in ...; do tar -czf $d.tar.gz $d; done`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

может не самое элегантное, но хорошо работающее решение:

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1| xargs -i tar -cvzf {}.tar.gz {}
```

объясняю что происходит:

> 1) 
>   find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1
>
> find — утилита для поиска и обхода файлов и директорий

. — текущий каталог

-type d — ключ для обхода только директрий в текущем каталоге

-maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 — глубина обхода после этого на stdout у нас подаются адреса каталогов которые нужно архивировать

2) `| xargs -i tar -cvzf {}.tar.gz {}`

> | — конвейер. переваёт вывод поманды в следующую команду
>
> xargs — утилита, помогающая формировать список аргументов
>
> -i — ключ,который говорит что мы будем что-то подставлять
>
> tar -cvzf {}.tar.gz {} — команда для архивации каталога по gz(вместо {} подставляется имя каталога, сформированное утилитой find).
>
> -{}.tar.gz — имя архива(каталог+"tar.gz") вторые {} — что директория для архивации

после этого в текущем каталоге у тебя появятся нужные тебе архивы , которые ты запросто можешь переместить в нужную тебе директорию командой:

```
find . -type f| grep tar.gz | xargs -i mv {} нужная/папка
```

Comment: сорри за оформление. лучше уже не сделаю

Comment: `tar` пропустил...

Comment: слишком много ошибок. проверяйте, пожалуйста, перед публикацией, предлагаемые команды.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin где ошибки? скрипт работает же

Comment: 1. скрипта в вашем ответе не вижу, вижу команду. 2. да, команда запускается, да, не зависает, да, завершает работу, да, выводит сообщение об ошибке в *stderr*. 3. да, если исправить самую грубую ошибку, то даже создаются файлы с архивами, правда, на один больше, чем требуется. 4. если всё это и является целью вашего ответа, то, да, ничего менять не надо. // p.s. `find . -type f| grep tar.gz` — рекомендую почитать `$ man find` на предмет опции `-name`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin добавил пропущенный "tar".не пойму  про какой "лишний" архив вы говорите. Всё работает.

Comment: архив для **всего** текущего каталога — явно лишний.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да, точно. исправил

Comment: *-print0* отсутствует.

Answer (score 1):

очевидно, что надо «пройтись» в цикле по всем именам каталогов, и для каждого из них вызвать программу *tar* с соответствующими аргументами.

- цикл. что-нибудь вроде:

  ```
  $ for n in *; do test -d $n && команда; done
  ```

  здесь `test -d имя` — вернёт истину, если `имя` является каталогом.
- соответствующие аргументы — это что-нибудь вроде:

  ```
  tar -czf имя.tgz имя
  ```

итого:

```
$ for n in *; do test -d $n && tar -czf $n.tgz $n; done
```

возможный недостаток: под маску `*` (по умолчанию) не подпадут файлы/каталоги, имена которых начинаются с символа `.` (точка).

---

альтернативным способом организации цикла может служить вызов программы *find* либо в связке с программой *xargs*:

```
$ find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | xargs -I '{}' tar -czf '{}'.tgz '{}'
```

либо с помещением нужной команды в «тело» опции `-exec`:

```
$ find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec tar -czf '{}'.tgz '{}' \;
```

Comment: Маска * — зло, перестаньте её уже употреблять в скриптах. Тем более не альтернативный, а единственно верный путь через _find_ упомянут.